# what is the meaning of "hint of a chip"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have been reading an article and I'm came across this sentence:

> He’s also a person: serious, thoughtful, merciful, the slightest hint of a chip on his shoulder.

I googled "hint of a chip" but can't find anything useful. what is the meaning of this phrase?

Comment: try 'chip on shoulder' - the person has a hint of that, meaning the person is slightly irritable.

Comment: The idiom used in the sentence is "chip on his shoulder". It means to have or hold some residual anger/resentment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a chip on one's shoulder is *to seem angry all the time because you think you have been treated unfairly or feel you are not as good as other people* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-chip-on-your-shoulder). A hint of a chip is just a very small chip, so the individual displays just a suggestion of resentment.